# why sometime ajax success function doesn't work in asp.net mvc?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatable

In my project, I've used `datatable` for crud operation.but I have a problem sometimes didn't work success function, of course, I saw my network tab I received `{ status":true}` but `datatable` didn't reload and I redirected to the blank page.I've added alert function into success function but my alert function didn't work.sometimes I got this error `The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.` when I want to delete a record from a table. and also sometimes `create` and `edit` give me `{ status":true}` message.

[image]

```
// GET: Admin/Users/Delete/5
public ActionResult Delete(string id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    User user = db.User.Find(id);
    UserViewModel userViewModel=new UserViewModel();
    userViewModel.UserId = user.Id;
    userViewModel.UserName = user.UserName;
    userViewModel.FirstName = user.FirstName;
    userViewModel.LastName = user.LastName;
    userViewModel.Email = user.Email;
    userViewModel.IsActive = user.IsActive;
    userViewModel.Gender = user.Gender;
    userViewModel.PhoneNumber = user.PhoneNumber;
    userViewModel.Address = user.Address;
    if (user == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return PartialView(userViewModel);
}

// POST: Admin/Users/Delete/5
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string id)
{
    bool status=false;
    User user = db.User.Find(id);
    db.User.Remove(user);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return Json(new { status = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

==========================

```
@model  IEnumerable<Dentistry.Areas.ViewModels.UserViewModel>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "مدیریت کاربران";

}

@*<h2>مدیریت کاربران</h2>*@

@section Styles{

    <link href="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/datatables/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/datatables.bootstrap-rtl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-modal/css/bootstrap-modal-bs3patch.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-modal/css/bootstrap-modal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}

<style>
    .table-checkable tr > td:first-child, .table-checkable tr > th:first-child {
        text-align: center;
        max-width: 50000px;
        min-width: 40px;
        padding-right: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #delete .modal-header {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
        background: #e7505a !important;
    }

    .modal {
        border-radius: 0px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    }
</style>


<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <!-- BEGIN EXAMPLE TABLE PORTLET-->
    <div class="portlet box green">
        <div class="portlet-title">
            <div class="caption">
                <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>کاربران
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
                <a href="/Admin/Users/Create" data-target="#create" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> کاربر جدید
                </a>
                <a href="javascript:window.print()" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                    <i class="fa fa-print"></i> چاپ
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portlet-body">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable order-column myDatatable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        @*<th class="table-checkbox">
                                <label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-single mt-checkbox-outline">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="group-checkable" data-set="myDatatable .checkboxes" />
                                    <span></span>
                                </label>
                            </th>*@
                        <th>نام کاربری </th>
                        <th>نام </th>
                        <th>نام خانوادگی</th>
                        <th>جنسیت</th>
                        <th>ایمیل</th>
                        <th>وضعیت</th>
                        <th>شماره تماس</th>
                        <th>آدرس</th>
                        <th>ویرایش</th>
                        <th>حذف</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>


            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<div id="edit" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="760">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">ویرایش کاربران</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">

        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="delete" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="760">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">آیا قصد حذف این کاربر را دارید؟</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">

        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="create" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="760">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>   کاربر جدید </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">


    </div>

</div>

<!-- BEGIN Portlet PORTLET-->
<!-- END Portlet PORTLET-->




@section scripts{


    <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
    <script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/scripts/datatable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/datatables/datatables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/datatables.bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/pages/scripts/table-datatables-managed.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- END PAGE LEVEL SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-modal/js/bootstrap-modalmanager.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-modal/js/bootstrap-modal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/pages/scripts/ui-extended-modals.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            var oTable = $('.myDatatable').DataTable({
                "ajax": "/Users/GetUsers",
                "language": {
                    "search": "جستجو:",
                    "lengthMenu": " تعداد _MENU_ رکورد در هر صفحه"
                },
                "autoWidth": true,
                "columns": [

                    { "data": "UserName", },
                    { "data": "FirstName", },
                    { "data": "LastName", },
                    { "data": "Gender", },
                    { "data": "Email", },
                    { "data": "IsActive", },
                    { "data": "PhoneNumber", },
                    { "data": "Address", },

                    {
                        "data": "UserId", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
                            //
                            return '<a class="btn btn-info fa fa-pencil" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#edit"  href="/Admin/Users/Edit/' + data + '"></a>';
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "UserId", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
                            return '<a class="btn btn-danger fa fa-trash" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#delete" href="/Admin/Users/Delete/' + data + '"></a>';
                        }
                    }
                    //}, {
                    //    "data": 'IsActive',
                    //    render: function (data, type, row) {
                    //        return '<span class="label label-sm label-success"> ' + data + ' </span>'
                    //    }
                    //}
                ], "columnDefs": [
                    {
                        "render": function (data, type, row) {
                            return '<span class="label label-sm label-success"> ' + data ? 'آقا' : 'خانم' + ' </span>' ;
                        },
                        "targets": 3 // replace 0 by your column if
                    }, {
                        "render": function (data, type, row) {
                            return data ? 'فعال' : 'غیرفعال';
                        },
                        "targets": 5
                    }
                ]
                //"fnCreatedRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
                //    var div = document.createElement("span");

                //    $(row).children("td:nth-child(1)").append(div);
                //}

            });

            $('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {

                $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
            });

        });


    </script>
}
```

===================================

```
  @model Dentistry.Areas.ViewModels.UserViewModel

@*<h2>حذف</h2>

    <h3>آیا شما قصد حذف این سطر را دارید؟</h3>*@
@*<div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">آیا شما قصد حذف این سطر را دارید؟</h4>
    </div>*@

@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Users", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "popupForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    if (Model != null && Model.UserId != string.Empty)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.UserId, new { id = "userId" })
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>نام کاربری : </label>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserName)
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>نام : </label>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>نام خانوادگی : </label>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>شماره همراه : </label>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>جنسیت</label>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Gender)
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>وضعیت : </label>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.IsActive)
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>ایمیل : </label>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>آدرس : </label>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Address)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <button type="submit" class="btn  btn-success btn-flat btn-md"><span class="fa fa-check"></span>  بله  </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat btn-md"><span class="fa fa-close"></span> خیر</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}

<script>

    $(function () {
        //var form = $('#userId');
        //console.log(form);
        console.log($('#userId').val());
        $(".popupForm").on("submit", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
           // e.stopPropagation();
            SubmitDeleteForm();

        });
    });
    function SubmitDeleteForm() {
        var formData = $(".popupForm").serialize();
        var url = "/Users/Delete";
           var form = $('.popupForm');
           var __RequestVerification =@Html.AntiForgeryToken();
           var token = $(__RequestVerification, form).val();
        //  var form = $('.popupForm')[0].action;
        //   console.log(form.val());
        //var formdata = false;
        //if (window.FormData) {
        //    formdata = new FormData(form);
        // alert(formdata);
        //}
        var userId = JSON.stringify({ id: $("#userId").val() });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: url,
            data: {

                __RequestVerificationToken: token,
                id: userId

            },

            cache: false,
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            //  enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.status == true) {
                    //alert('hiho');
                    $('#edit').modal('hide');
                    //window.location.href = "/Admin/Users/Index";
                    alert('hi');
                    $('.myDatatable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }

        });
    }



</script>
```

Comment: I've read a lot of links in StackOverflow but they couldn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove this line

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
```

because you are not sending anti forgery key. send anti forgery key in ajax parameters or remove this.

for sending add this parameter in request '__RequestVerificationToken' with its value which you will generate using
var token = Html.AntiForgeryToken();

Comment: __RequestVerificationToken is solved thanks but I also I got this message **{status:true}** in fact, my record added into table or record removed but I also redirected blank page. I've added an image to my question. success function didn't work.

Comment: @rayan i have found several other problems, first you have a form and than you have an ajax. when you click button it submits form that is why you are redirected. what you can do is on click of button serialise data of form and add it in ajax call

Comment: @rayan other option is to use Ajax.BeginForm